# Skipping rows and columns when reading csv with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need help about read csv file with pandas.
I have a .csv file that recorded machine parameters and want to read this excel with pandas and analyze. But problem is this excel file not in a proper table format. That means there are a lot of empty rows and columns. Also parameter values are starting from 301st line (example).

How can I read as properly this csv file?

[image]

Comment: To drop a empty row while reading you can use thsi`df = pd.read_csv('your_csv.path', skip_blank_lines=True)`. please provide model output or code that you had tried for better clarification.

Comment: Please edit your post and include a sample of the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You can use skiprows:

pd.read_csv(csv_file, skiprows=301)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: but the rows and columns I want to read are in separate places. That's why, I need to read all of them at once.

Comment: Please provide a dummy example DataFrame

Comment: I added dummy example in the main post. There are data in the black marked places and I want to access them. In addition, it continues in this way in different structures downwards.

Comment: Is the structure fixed, or variable? If the number of empty row is constant, you can read it in parts, each time skipping a different number of rows.

You can also read it as raw text instead of Pandas DF and break it up yourself.

Is CSV the native filetype that the machine generates? If it also generates TDMS that might be more convenient.

Comment: Yes, structure is fixed. Also, csv is generated by machine. I'll try to read again with Pandas step by step for each empty lines/columns. Thanks a lot